# Am I still Muslim, and married to my husband, after saying bad words out of anger?

Tags: nikah, forgiveness, kufr, anger

New convert concerns:  Am I still Muslim if a said bad words out of anger that I couldn't control when I had my menses?

I really get it bad and the pain and mood swings. I blamed Eve for all woman being punished by it. I didn't mean it. And felt very bad after I said it I cried myself to sleeping asking forgiveness. But my husband says our nikah is broken now and I'm not Muslim anymore.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE!  (And welcome to Islam too!)  I'm fairly sure both you and your husband are overreacting to all this (someone more knowledgeable than me should be able to answer this).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are :) Not all sins are blasphemy.  By cussing, you've committed a sin (and seems like you regret your actions so make tawbah/repent) but you have not rejected the deen so you're fine, sister :)

My suggestion would be to find a better way to release your anger.